# Removing first character under condition - formula

Tags: formula

I came to ask for help about formula with multiple conditions, unfortunately I didn't manage any attempt to work properly. I appreciate any suggestions :).

If National Id. Number begins with 0 and has 10 characters, we need to remove only the first zero.

If National Id. Number has less than 10 characters we don't have to do anything

Also trick here is, that field national identification number is mix with numbers and letters.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the attempt(s) that you've made so far.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your National Id field name is `Nid__c`, following formula would do that.

```
If(
  And(
    Begins(Nid__c, '0'),
    If(Len(Nid__c) == 10, true, false)
  ),
  Right(Nid__c, Len(Nid__c) - 1),
  Nid__c
)
```